# CSS3 toggle down effect, repeated, not working, why?

Tags: css, toggle

I'm trying to create different links that toggle down different content when clicked:

```
<section id="slidebox">
    <div id="toggle">
        <a class="bot" href="#">Push me</a>
        <a class="top" href="#slidebox">Push me</a>
    </div>
    <div id="box">    
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </div>
</section> 

<section id="slidebox">
    <div id="toggle">
        <a class="bot" href="#">Push me 2</a>
        <a class="top" href="#slidebox">Push me 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="box">    
        OTHER CONTENT
    </div>
</section>
```

The CSS code for this:

```
#toggle {
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#toggle a { position: absolute; }

#toggle {
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#toggle a { position: absolute; }

#box {
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:0;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

#slidebox:target #box {
    max-height:100px;
    opacity:1;
}

#slidebox:target .top { opacity:0;pointer-events: none;}
```

I want to repeat that  horizontally like in column per section, but with different text/content. The problem is that when doing it (using `float:left`), when you click a different section, it triggers and slides down the 1st section's content.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to make columns in a row with independent  and content? This is driving me nuts!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that you were using the same ID multiple times. ***DON'T DO THAT***. It creates problems no matter what you're doing and is incorrect form. Use classes instead, only use IDs to obtain a specific object

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/UR4Up/)

```
/* CSS */
.toggle {
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
.toggle a { position: absolute; }
.box {
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:0;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
}
.slidebox:target .box {
    max-height:100px;
    opacity:1;
}
.slidebox:target .top { opacity:0; pointer-events: none;}

/* HTML */
<section id="pushOne" class="slidebox">
    <div class="toggle">
        <a class="bot" href="#">Push me</a>
        <a class="top" href="#pushOne">Push me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">    
        Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </div>
</section> 

<section id="pushTwo" class="slidebox">
    <div class="toggle">
        <a class="bot" href="#">Push me 2</a>
        <a class="top" href="#pushTwo">Push me 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">    
        OTHER CONTENT
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Zeaklous. I'm going to try it and see if it works :)

Comment: I tried and it worked perfectly! AMAZING! I wish I had your skill and experience to have guessed something that silly... Thank you so much!! Great help!

Comment: No problem at all. And I have been coding for less time that you have, just check how long I've been on SO, haha

Comment: Then, yours is pure talent! :)